# How to limit this foreach loop to 10 loops?

Tags: php

How can I limit the code below to show 10 loops.

```
        foreach( $entries as $entry ) {
            echo '<tr>';
            $fields = wpforms_decode( $entry->fields );
            foreach( $fields as $field ) {
                if ( in_array( $field['id'], $ids)) {
                    echo '<td>' . apply_filters( 'wpforms_html_field_value', wp_strip_all_tags( $field['value'] ), $field, $form_data, 'entry-frontend-table' );
                }
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
```

Comment: Which of them??

Comment: Maybe `$entries as $key => $entry... if($key > 10 ) { break;`? Show the array structure

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to write your code for you. there are thousands of resources available on iteration and loops in PHP (and any language for that matter). what have you tried? why are you writing it this way? why does it need to stop at 10?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possibility where the loop to break is the first one:

```
foreach( $entries as $key=>$entry ) 
{
    if($key==9) break;
    echo '<tr>';
    $fields = wpforms_decode( $entry->fields );

    foreach( $fields as $field ) 
    {
        if ( in_array( $field['id'], $ids)) 
        {
            echo '<td>' . apply_filters( 'wpforms_html_field_value', wp_strip_all_tags( $field['value'] ), $field, $form_data, 'entry-frontend-table' );
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Another possiblity where the loop to break is the second one:

```
foreach( $entries as $entry ) 
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $fields = wpforms_decode( $entry->fields );
    foreach( $fields as $key=>$field ) 
    {
        if($key==9) break;
        if ( in_array( $field['id'], $ids)) 
        {
            echo '<td>' . apply_filters( 'wpforms_html_field_value', wp_strip_all_tags( $field['value'] ), $field, $form_data, 'entry-frontend-table' );
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

If you want to stop the whole process / method / function you might want to use return instead of break. Break will just stop the current loop process.

Comment: You need to note this presumes OP isn't using associative array. https://3v4l.org/TrnPo

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $entries as $entry ) {
    $i++;
    if ($i > 9 ) break; // this will stop after the 10th loop and in the beginning of loop 11
    echo '<tr>';
    $fields = wpforms_decode( $entry->fields );
    foreach( $fields as $field ) {
        // if you want to stop this loop too use $ii not $i 
        // but notice stopping this loop will not stop the parent loop !
        if ( in_array( $field['id'], $ids)) {
            echo '<td>' . apply_filters( 'wpforms_html_field_value', wp_strip_all_tags( $field['value'] ), $field, $form_data, 'entry-frontend-table' );
        }
     }
     echo '</tr>';
}
```